# Adjust vector subset values according to certain rules

Tags: r

I am trying to code a function that converts Chinese numerals to Arabic. 
The idea is to get a set of `scaled_digit` vectors and a set of `scale_factor` vectors, multiply and add them up to generate the desired output.

```
digit=c('〇'=0,'一'=1,'二'=2,'三'=3,'四'=4,'五'=5,'六'=6,'七'=7,'八'=8,'九'=9)
scale=c('十'=10^1,'百'=10^2,'千'=10^3,'萬'=10^4,'億'=10^8,'兆'=10^12)
```

One of the problems I encounter is this:

When I have a number that is a few hundred `10^4`s (萬) and a few thousand `10^12`s (兆), I am left with a scale-factor vector that is as follows:

```
scale_factor=
structure(c(1000, 1e+12, 100, 10, 10000, 1000, 100, 10), .Names = c("千", 
"兆", "百", "十", "萬", "千", "百", "十"))

   [千]     兆    [百]    [十]    萬    千    百    十 
  [1e+03] 1e+12 [1e+02] [1e+01] 1e+04 1e+03 1e+02 1e+01
```

*Scale factors to be adjusted have been marked by [ ].*

The positions of the cardinal `scale_factors` can be found with the following code:

```
cardinal_scale_factor=which(diff(scale_factor)>=0, T)+1

兆 萬 
 2  5
```

How do I code so that `scale_factor[1]` and `scale_factor[3:4]` can be multiplied by `scale_factor[2]` and `[5]` respectively?

---

**Expected result:**

```
   [千]     兆    [百]    [十]    萬    千    百    十 
  [1e+15] 1e+12 [1e+06] [1e+05] 1e+04 1e+03 1e+02 1e+01
```

Comment: One attempt at the next logical step is: 
`mapply(seq, cardinal_scale_factor)
$兆
[1] 1 2

$萬
[1] 1 2 3 4 5`

Any ideas how to continue from here?

Comment: I am probably looking to morph the above result into this: `$兆
[1] 1 

$萬
[1]  3 4`, then the rest should be easy.

Comment: I don't understand the problem, neither what are you trying to do. Why are you multiplying those vectors and how is it related to Arabic? Why are you calculating the `diff`? Why `diff  >= 0` is important? Why are you multiplying  `scale_factor[1]` and `scale_factor[3:4]` by `scale_factor[2]` and `[5]`? Why those entries in particular, What about the rest of the entries? I have absolutely no understanding of what's going on in this question

Comment: @DavidArenburg, basically, in the Chinese numeral system, there are multipliers that indicate the scale (10^x) of a certain digit preceding it. One of the scales we are dealing with over here is the _wan_, equivalent to ten thousand (10^4), so now I have a couple of hundreds of ten thousands (say, 250) in my number. But the `scale_factor` vector does not reflect this. So `250*10^4` is just calculated as 250, which is not what I needed.

Comment: In a simple situation, the `scale_factor` vector should be always decreasing, from left to right. Eg. 3 million, 2 thousand 5 hundred and 1. So we have `10^6, 10^3, 10^2` in sequence. It gets complicated when we have 210 thousand in our number, because 10^2 and 10^1 would be sandwiched between the cardinal scale factors of 10^6 and 10^3, which is why we need to pick them out and multiply them by their respective cardinal factors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
w1 <- which(rev(cummax(rev(scale_factor)) > rev(scale_factor)))

grp <- cumsum(c(1,diff(w1)) > 1) + 1

w2 <- aggregate(w1, list(grp), max)[[2]] + 1

scale_factor[w1] <- scale_factor[w1] * scale_factor[w2][grp]
```

which gives:

> ```
> > scale_factor
>    千    兆    百    十    萬    千    百    十 
> 1e+15 1e+12 1e+06 1e+05 1e+04 1e+03 1e+02 1e+01
> ```

What this does:

1. With `cummax(rev(scale_factor))` you get the cummulative maximum of the reversed scale.
2. Comparing that with the reversed scale (`cummax(rev(scale_factor)) > rev(scale_factor)`) gives a logical vector.
3. Wrapping the logical vector from step 2 in `rev` and `which` subsequently, wou get an index vector of positions `w1` that do not conform to the decreasing condition.
4. With `cumsum(c(1,diff(w1)) > 1) + 1` you can group these positions for case the 3rd and 4th values in the example data.
5. With `aggregate(w1, list(grp), function(x) max(x) + 1)[[2]]` you determine the positions of the multipliers.
6. Finally, you multiply the values in `scale_factor` as determined in `w1` with the multipliers from `w2`. You need to index `w2` with the group numbers from `grp`.